# How to change column type from text to date in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I uploaded a csv file to a mysql database. Inside the table there is a time column, which has as the name already says time information :), please have a look
This column is saved as text

[image: Time information is saved as text type]

I try to convert time column in datetime, and found following help on stackoverflow [MySQL alter table and convert data from text to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073973/mysql-alter-table-and-convert-data-from-text-to-datetime)

So I tried to go the same way, i.e.

```
 alter table 'tablename' add column new_column_name date;

 update 'tablename'
 set new_column_name=str_to_date(column_with_time_saved_as_text,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
```

If I execute the script I get following error
**Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '2019-07-03 23:47:46.254+02' for function str_to_date**

I suppose there is an issue with the timezone.I tried to find out a solution but I could not. Thanks for any kind of advice

Comment: Why not create a new table with correct datatype, and insert the data from source to new one and do some fiddling remving the + all data after using substring_index?

Comment: You may find this useful for your case
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961490/mysql-error-code-1411-incorrect-datetime-value-for-function-str-to-date

Comment: @Kay. I dont understand your approach. I get a csv file and upload it to mysql DB as a new table. Even if I create a new table I will have the same issue to convert the column type from text to date :)

Comment: @SMS please see my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

> Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '2019-07-03
>   23:47:46.254+02' for function str_to_date

means that you are using a wrong formatting parameter, as explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) you must use formatters in the form `%dateField` like this:

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE("August 10 2017", "%M %d %Y");
```

Alternatively, you can use [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to get only the datetime part you need:

```
alter table 'tablename' add column new_column_name datetime;
update 'tablename' set new_column_name = SUBSTRING(column_with_time_saved_as_text, 1, 19)
```

Comment: if I execute your code I only the year information, i.e. 2019-07-03

Comment: @SMS because the new filed was setted as DATE instead of DATETIME. see my  edit (`add column new_column_name datetime;`)

Comment: ah perfect. than you very very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform str_to_date

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('2019-11-03 23:59:46.254+02', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') dt;

         dt
   2019-11-03 23:59:46
```

Using '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' update the table

```
    alter table 'tablename' add column new_column_name datetime;

    update 'tablename'
    set new_column_name= DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(column_with_time_saved_as_text,19), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

But this will ignore the '254+02'.

Comment: I also used this code but I also get the same message "Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2019-07-03 23:47:46.254+02'
"

Comment: Maybe try to take only datetime part :

update tablename set  new_column_name = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(left(column_with_time_saved_as_text,19), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s %x'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s %x');