# STR_TO_TIME convert

Tags: mysql

have a string field in DB which I need to convert to datetime, my problem is I need to convert date format from 03/01/2019 11:30 to 2011-01-26 14:30:00. I can do it with an individual record, but can't figure out how to convert all the records in the table.

I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073973/mysql-alter-table-and-convert-data-from-text-to-datetime)

but, all converted dates are 0000-00-00 00:00:00 presumably because mysql not able to guess input date format.

```
create table wms_lw.wms_lw (
site_id int null, 
name varchar(255) null,
site varchar(255) null,
date varchar(255) null, 
new_date datetime not null, 
value double null, 
date_2 varchar(255) null 
);
```

Comment: add table structure with field data types

Comment: create table wms_lw.wms_lw  
(  
    site_id  int          null,  
    name     varchar(255) null,  
    site     varchar(255) null,  
    date     varchar(255) null,  
    new_date datetime     not null,  
    value    double       null,  
    date_2   varchar(255) null  
);

Comment: first off all, its not good to store date, timestamp as varchar in database, you can use timestamp or datetime type.

Comment: `UPDATE wms_lw.wms_lw SET date = STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%M-%Y %h:%i')` you can use this query to change date format in all rows

Comment: @Zeljka agree, not sure how to convert the date formats other than str_to_date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date

Comment: Wouldn't that UPDATE give me the same format?

Comment: `UPDATE wms_lw.wms_lw SET date = date_format(str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i'), '%Y-%m-/%d %h:%i:%s'); `

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string in date  as

```
select str_to_date('03/01/2019 11:30', '%d/%m/%Y %i:%s')
```

so from your table

```
select str_to_date(my_col, '%d/%m/%Y %i:%s') from my_table
```

once you have a date  you can format as you prefer wit  `date_format()`  or add the datte time using `date_Add()`